# ¿Cómo condicionar un evento de textbox de un userform para que ocurra una sola ocasión?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy desarrollando un formulario en Excel, usando VBA. Este formulario contiene textboxes, sin embargo, una vez que he ingresado información en una caja, me muevo hacia y regreso a ella, quiero que me seleccione el texto con un click, y con dos o más, me permita la edición normal. He intentado utilizar mousedown, pero no funciona, porque se repite cada vez que hago click sobre la caja de texto. Por eso, quiero condicionar para que mousedown solo se ejecute una vez cuando se ha pulsado sobre una caja.
Agrego que gotfocus no está disponible para codificar la selección.

Comment: *quiero condicionar para que mousedown solo se ejecute una vez* Prueba a jugar con una variable pública booleana que dependiendo de si es True/False sí se mousedown o no.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una solución a está dinámica de mousedown cuando se usa el editor VBA de Excel.

Procedo a mostrar mi código inicial:

```
Private Sub Txt_Razon_social_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'Se desactiva la actualización en pantalla, para evitar parpadeos
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Esta macro sirve que al hacer click sobre el cuadro de texto, se seleccione todo el texto contenido
    With Txt_Razon_social
         .SelStart = 0
         .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
End sub
```

Sin embargo, presenta que cada vez que pulso sobre la caja, si tiene texto, lo selecciona, y así indefinidamente. Para solucionarlo, ideé el siguiente proceso:

1 En un módulo del proyecto, creo una variable pública para recoger el número de mousedown sobre las cajas de texto.

```
Option Explicit
'La variable pública que aquí declaro va a recoger el número de mousedown sobre las cajas de textos
Public Seleccionador As Byte
```

2 Declaro con valor 0 la variable en el evento Initialize del userform.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Se desactiva la actualización en pantalla, para evitar parpadeos
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'El contador de mousedown lo declaro en 0 para cada vez que se carga el formulario
Seleccionador = 0
End Sub
```

3 Establezco los parámetros para el mousedown utilizando la variable contadora (Dim Seleccionador). Creo una

```
Private Sub Txt_Razon_social_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'Se desactiva la actualización en pantalla, para evitar parpadeos
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'El contador dinámico permite recoger el número de mousedown sobre la caja, permitiendo establecer la siguiente condición
Seleccionador = Seleccionador + Button
'Activo el objeto para trabajar sobre él
With Txt_Razon_social
'Declaro la condición en la que con menos de un mousedown, se seleccione el texto
     If Seleccionador <= 1 Then
          .SelStart = 0
          .SelLength = Len(.Text)
'En cambio, cuando el número de mousedown es mayor a 1 o el objeto está vacío, simplemente se posiciona el curso para editar el objeto
     ElseIf Txt_Razon_social= Empty Or Seleccionador > 1 Then
          .SetFocus
     End If
End With
End Sub
```

4 Parametrizo el evento Exit para restablecer el contador (Dim Seleccionador) y poder aplicar la variable sobre otros objetos.

```
Private Sub Txt_Razon_social_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'Se desactiva la actualización en pantalla, para evitar parpadeos
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Al seleccionar el foco en otro lugar del formulario, el cursor se posiciona al inicio del cuadro de texto
With Txt_Razon_social
    .SelStart = 0
End With 
'Cuando el foco sale de la caja de texto seleccionada, el contador vuelve a 0, permitiendo reiniciar el mousedown.
Seleccionador = 0
End Sub
```